# Sound - Volume always starts on full

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I was trying to improve my sound quality a little (Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 700-15ISK) by installing the pulse equalizer `qpaeq` and `pavucontrol`.

Sice I installed the two programs, everytime I play some media containing sound, the volume is on full setting. When lower the volume, pause the media and then press play again, it behaves normally and remembers the setting, however when I close the media and open another, the volume is on full again.

Every time I play a video or an mp3 track, a new volume bar appears in `pavucontrol` that is on 100% and so is the volume bar called *Stream Equalized On* (only visible after selecting *All Streams*).

I tried putting back the default flat preset in `qpaeq` that I saved in the begining, but it didn't work. I tried [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=749018&p=4675606#post4675606), but it didn't work either.

What could cause the volume to be always at 100 % by default and not remembering its state even without the PC rebooting? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem -- I remembered that I also found that for `pulseaudio-equalizer` to work you need to add the following lines to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-equalizer-sink
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

After commenting them, my problem disappeared, so the problem must have been in the equalizer. Unfortunately, I didn't discover a way to fix it. If you did, please share your way.